# Run chrome.tabs.executeScript only when the new tab is created and loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, execute-script

I am trying to create a chrome extension to automate the login process.

I am able to login the website using Process_login2 (fill in the username and password and click login button).

However, when I use Process_login (with addon function to open tab and navigate to the webpage), the login function is failed.

Do you have any idea how to run the script only when the new tab is created and loaded?

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var Process_login = document.querySelector('#menu_btn_login');
  var Process_login2 = document.querySelector('#menu_btn_login2');
  var Process_SendingMsg = document.querySelector('#menu_btn_sendingMsg');

  Process_login.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      var url_login = 'https://example.com/#login';
      chrome.permissions.request({ origins: [url_login] }, granted => {
        if (granted) {
          chrome.tabs.create({ url: url_login }, tab => {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: 'scripts/login.js' });
          });
        } else {
          alert('You need to grant permission');
        }
      });
    });
  });

  Process_login2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'scripts/login.js' });
    });
  });
```

```
permissions": 
        [
        "tabs",
        "tabCapture",
        "activeTab",
        "declarativeContent", 
        "storage"]
```

Comment: Replace `tab => function (tab) {` with `tab => {`

Comment: @wOxxOm thx, i have updated the code but it does not work.....

Comment: Also replace `tabs[0].id` with `tab.id` in the same function.

Comment: @wOxxOm still does not work.  file: 'scripts/login.js' is not called.

Comment: What's in `permissions` of manifest.json? Also, these kind of problems should be trivial to resolve if you start using devtools debugger: set breakpoints inside callbacks and run the code to see/inspect what happens. Just in case, [How to open the correct devtools console to see output from an extension script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)

Comment: @wOxxOm i have updated permissions of manifest.json

Comment: Ah, that's because the newly opened tab wasn't activated by the user. See the description of [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission. It won't work in this case so you will have to add `https://example.com/` to `permissions`.